# Microsoft Outlook API Costing model

Tags: outlook-api

Im working on a small project in my company where I'm using Outlook REST APIs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

So far so good.

The application is also registered in Microsoft Azure Active Directory. As explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular?context=outlook%2Fcontext

Our application is permanently running and needs to get data every like 1 minute.
This causes a lot of requests.

So are there any costs regarding Microsoft Api that I should know about.
Or is the Calendar Api completely free.
Didn't find any helpful information out there so far.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Check Microsoft Graph API. Which uses all the Office 365 Apps connected with API endpoints.

[Microsoft 365 pricing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/compare-office-365-plans)